# More Visual Rebuses

Tags: rebus

Here are some rebuses for your entertainment! There is no central theme, although all of the solutions consist of multiple words.

*This is my first attempt at designing a rebus puzzle. I made these rebuses in an image editor. Some of them contain graphics that I found online.*

1. [image: One] 4. [image: Four]
2. [image: Two] 5. [image: Five]
3. [image: Three] 6. [image: Six]

Hint for #6:

> We're no strangers to rebus puzzles...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial answer (not confident in the last one)

1.

> See [Techidiot's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48182/31484).

2.

> **SEPARATE THE WHEAT FROM THE CHAFF** ((C + HALF) - (W + HEAT))

3.

> **SUNRISE AND SUNSET** (SUN + R + I'S & SET whose element is the SUN)

4.

> **WATER UNDER THE BRIDGE** (H2O UNDER BRIDGE hand, which consists of 13 cards)

5.

> **CAT IN THE HAT** (C+AT IN the H+AT)

6.

> **NO USE REFLECTING**??? (NO U'S reflecting across the diagonal)

Comment: Only 5 of 6 correct, but you got the most of them first, so I'm marking this as the answer.  [Rubio answered](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48433/30304) [$6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) after the hint update.

Answer (score 4):

Partial

1.

> To Infinity and Beyond

2.

> Water under the bridge - Thanks @Silenus.

3.

> Second half could be W+Heat= Wheat. So may be See Half Wheat or Fraction of Wheat.

4.

> Hydrocarbonates/Bicarbonates(H-Hydrogen, C-Carbon, @-at's)

5.

> Sunrise Sunset.

6.

> Wrong Turn

Answer (score 3):

6.

> Never gonna give "U" up
>  Never gonna let "U" down   ...?

Comment: Good answer, but does it satisfy the hint?

Comment: You really never know when it's going to happen do you?

Comment: The hint is what made me give this answer to begin with